Looking for review of delay differential equations involving $f(x)$ and $f(x/k)$
A research problem unexpectedly leads me to a delay differential equation of the form
$$
f(x)=\alpha(f(x),f(x/2))\,f'(x)+\beta(f(x),f(x/2))\,f'(x/2)+\gamma(f(x),f(x/2))
$$
For special cases of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, I know that the solution is an arbitrary quadratic polynomial in $x$, but I need a more general case (maybe not exactly the most general case, though).
Is there a good review of existence and (non-?)uniqueness results, maximum principles (or similar), and solution methods for delay differential equations of such types (i.e. involving $f(x)$ and $f(x/k)$ rather than $f(x)$ and $f(x-\tau)$)?

Wouldn't a logarithmic substitution on the time domain transform this equation to a delay-differential equation of the more well-known type?

Yes, but I have initial data at x=0, which seems like a logarithmic substitution would not be too kind to it.

In spite of offering a bounty, this question did not get an answer, so it may be that there is no such review.
The closest thing that I could find is the book Polyanin et al., Delay Ordinary and Partial Differential Equations, which appears to treat proportional delay equations. I have to check if my library has a copy and if it contains more general results than what I could see in the preview (where mostly special cases were treated).
